# Available pagefile size / virtual memory

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management, cpu-architecture

What is the difference between `Process.PagedMemorySize64` and `PagedSystemMemorySize64` . I could not understand this clearly.
Also , I am looking for a way to find out how much of the paging file is still availalbe. Do I have to loop through all the processes and sum up the `PagedMemorySize64` for each one and subtract this from the total size of paging file ?

Answer (score 4):

PagedSystemMemorySize64 is the total number bytes of operating system kernel memory in the paged memory pool attributed to the process.  It corresponds with the "Paged Pool" column in Taskmgr.exe.

PagedMemorySize64 is the total number of bytes of user mode virtual memory allocated for the process.  It corresponds with the "Commit Size" column in Taskmgr.exe.

Note that processes share memory in these sections, the sum of the allocations of all processes is much greater than the actual amount of memory used.  You furthermore cannot reasonably calculate the amount of "unused" space in the paging file, Windows dynamically expands and shrinks it based on what running processes require.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Currently I have configured pagingFileSize to 16 gb. I want to check -- if the pagingFileSize is less than 3gb or so , kill some processes. Any hints ? How will I make this check for available pagingFile size ?