# Commit size of a process in Task Manager C#

Tags: c#, process, taskmanager

I need to get the 'Commit size' (Windows Task Manager > Details) of a process in C#.

[image]

At first sight the [`Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class does not provide a relevant property.
Can somebody help me?

**Edited**

```
 private static void ShowCommitSize(string processName)
    {
        Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).FirstOrDefault();
        if (process != null)
        {
            var pagedMemMb = ConvertBytesToMegabytes(process.PagedMemorySize64);
            Console.WriteLine(process.ProcessName + "\t" + process.Id + "\t" + Math.Round(pagedMemMb, 3) + " MB");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }    

    static double ConvertBytesToMegabytes(long bytes)
    {
        return (bytes / 1024f) / 1024f;
    }
```

**Output**

There is a difference between my calculated Commit Size and the 'Commit Size' in Task Manager. Any ideas?

[image]

**Solution**

```
private static void ShowCommitSize(string processName)
    {
        var process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).FirstOrDefault();
        if (process != null)
        {
            var memKb = ConvertBytesToKilobytes(process.PagedMemorySize64);
            Console.WriteLine(process.ProcessName + "\t" + process.Id + "\t" + memKb.ToString("N") + " K");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }    

    static double ConvertBytesToKilobytes(long bytes)
    {
        return (bytes / 1024f);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Available pagefile size / virtual memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590162/available-pagefile-size-virtual-memory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This value is in the [PagedMemorySize64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.pagedmemorysize64(v=vs.110).aspx) property. The documentation mentions that this the "Page File Size" process performance counter and over [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965225(v=vs.85).aspx) it is documented that this is referred to as "Commit Size" in Task Manager on Vista/2008 (and I would assume newer OSes).

Comment: thank you! I've edited my question, and used the  PagedMemorySize64 property. There is still a difference between calculated Commit Size and the value seen in Task Manager. Any ideas?

Comment: @BertAR which part of the difference are you asking about? 124552 Kb = 121.6 Mb. Are you asking about the 0.6 Mb or mistakenly comparing kB to Mb? Did the value change between screenshots?

Comment: thank you for the swift replies! Indeed my conversion was wrong. Have a nice day.

Comment: @BertAR I'm looking into this now. What was the issue with your conversion? I think I know what the problem was but I wanted to make sure before I added it to the answer.